# Access point IP range

Tags: ip, wireless-access-point, static-ip

I have 2 routers set up as access points on my network, with static addresses outside the range of the main router.  Should I configure the IP range of the access points to be OUTSIDE the range of the main router.  All equipment will connect to the internet via one of the access points

Comment: If I recall correctly, Access Points don't have IPs. Whether they hand out IPs(DHCP), i'm not sure, perhaps not

Answer (score 2):

**Turn off all DHCP services but the one on your internet gateway router.** Most devices think themselves the router and, as such, will make internet access impossible if they’re just an access point.

This is of course only valid if your access points are connected to your network with one of their LAN ports (as opposed to the WAN port). Which is the best option, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you mean is that your router has a range for DHCP of lets say 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.100.
You would like to put your static devices such as your access point outside of that range like 192.168.1.150? If so yes, ANY devices on your home network like printers, desktops, apple tv, Roku, wireless TV, ect. I would put a static address. It will likely help you with any troubleshooting in the future.

If your AP's do not have the ability of DHCP router or that function is turned off, your devices that connect to it will still get a address from the DHCP range of the router unless you configure otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  So it doesn't matter what range is assigned to the APs? They don't themselves need a range that is outside the DHCP router.  Just their own static IP needs to be outside the range.  I'm not likely to get any conflicts if the ranges of the APs were the range of the main router

Comment: Correct, you can statically assign the AP's to have any address you want in that range example: 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254, that is a typical range for home routers. If you make the DHCP pool or range from 1 - 100 I would put all static devices after that so 101 - 254. Now you could add it statically even from the range your router gives DHCP addresses but it is not recommended because if you have enough devices getting their address from DHCP it could cause a conflict.